# How to remove non-alphanumeric characters in a column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Using *sqlite3*, I have a simple table like this:

```
ArtistID Name             
---------------------------------
0        andres segovia      
1        andres|segovia|       
2        ?andres-segovia        
3        andres segovia and john 
4        anya marina          
5        aphex twin          
6        aphex-twin
```

What would a select look like in order to see results like this:

```
ArtistID Name             
---------------------------------
0        andressegovia      
1        andressegovia       
2        andressegovia        
3        andressegoviaandjohn 
4        anyamarina          
5        aphextwin          
6        aphextwin
```

I've tried using the regex capability by including the line ".load /usr/lib/sqlite3/pcre.so" into my ~/.sqliterc file but using REGEXP in a query returns weird results ending in "Error: no string" so perhaps there is a clearer way?

Comment: For anyone else running into it, the "no string" error happens when you compare against data. You can work around it with this module by doing an `IS NOT NULL` comparison before doing the `REGEXP` operation. A proper fix would probably be to patch pcre.so to treat null data as an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  replace(replace(replace(replace(name, 
    ' ', ''),
    '|', ''),
    '?', ''),
    '-', '') FROM your_table
```

Comment: This worked well, the nested replaces were the key.  Ti ringrazio!

Comment: @BrandonMinton: glad to help you. Prego!

Comment: This works well for the example data set. But the question was about removing ALL non-alpha chars. What if you don't know ahead of time which non-alpha chars exist in your data set? Is there a design that works in SQLite for this?